# All rounded corners TitleWindow in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

how can i get a title window with all rounded courners, so that i may make it whole round or circular shape ?
i want shape like circle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possible approaches:

If you are using Flex 4 (spark TitleWindow as opposed to the halo TitleWindow) you can create your own skin and assign that skin in CSS.  In your custom skin you can draw the background however you want, including an Ellipse set to the width and height of the TitleWindow.

If you don't want to create a skin, or you are using a halo TitleWindow, you can create a circular mask and set it as the mask property on the TitleWindow.  The downside to this approach is that you will probably clip the title and the close button (if it is visible), not to mention the contents as well.

Hope that helps, let me know if you need more details on either of these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

set the property: cornerRadius

default is 4